# Webview stealing click, touchstart, touchend events

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I'm converting a Chrome app into electron.  The app itself runs a provided URL in full screen kiosk mode (with a few other config options).  I want the ability to detect clicks in the renderer process on the parent element of the webview, however the webview "steals" clicks, touchstarts, and touchends, while "sharing" mousedown and mouseup.
I created a very basic app with a webpage containing a webview pointing to a blank webpage.  I added click, mousedown, and mouseup listeners to document in both the code within the webview and within the parent process.  If I click outside the webview, the parent's dev console outputs "mousedown mouseup click" but if I click on the webview the parent's dev console outputs "mousedown mouseup" and the webview's dev console outputs "mousedown mouseup click"

This app is designed to be used mainly with touchscreens so mousedown/mouseup are not a solution.  I need click, touchstart, and touchend to work.  Why do mousedown and mouseup bubble up from the webview while touchstart, touchend, and click do not?

Intention is to allow for an interactive page to be loaded in the webview but have some gestural shortcuts that the main process watches for, such as a sequence of clicks to reload the webview. See code below.

** I feel dumb.  Of course it works in Chromium browser, webview isn't even a valid tag there. Please ignore my previous edit.

Parent Process:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          console.log('click');
        })
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
          console.log('mousedown');
        })
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
          console.log('mouseup');
        })
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
          console.log('touchstart');
        });
        document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
          console.log('touchend');
        });
        document.getElementById('webview').openDevTools();
      }, 1000);
    </script>
    <title>Electron Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <webview id="webview" src="http://localhost/blank.html" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Webview Process:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log('webview click');
    });
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      console.log('webview mousedown');
    });
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
      console.log('webview mouseup');
    });
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
      console.log('webview touchstart');
    });
    document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
      console.log('webview touchend');
    });
  </script>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

of course. webview is iframe, iframe will not bubble these events